# “An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format” - Unknown program

Tags: windows

I posted this on SE and was pointed here. I also told to give more information however this is literally all I have. - Every now and then a random error message appears on my computer stating: "An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B). Please reinstall the product or contact support." I have found a few threads on this same issue, however in my situation, I have no idea what the actual affected program is. The error seems to show up at random times regardless of what I am currently doing. Ive tried searching the Event viewer and havent found anything. Is there anyway to find the source of the issue to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to tell us what program is generating this error. You can find this out by using Task Manager, or the Event Viewer, or the Startup application list

Answer (score 0):

First, perform a thorough scan for malware, using first your current AV tool, and then another such as the free [Malwarebytes](https://www.malwarebytes.com/) version.

Second, since you can't associate the event with any application, check Scheduled Tasks. The easiest way to search is with a free tool, Nirsoft's [TaskSchedulerView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/task_scheduler_view.html). You can order by *Last Run*, to compare with the time you noticed the pop-up, and search for the failure code, hex 0x8007000B, which is 2147942411 decimal.

[image: TaskSchedulerView]